# How can i handle an error image that doenst exist in a local folder

Tags: angular, image, error-handling, ionic4, local

I have list that shows a bunch of information and a function in img tag that searches for an specific image for that information in a local folder, but some of that information doenst have an image and i want to handle this error, and dont show it in the console, because it is flooding my console

[image]

anyone knows a way to handle this ?

Edit: the code that catch the image from the local folder

```js
  getImageBySymbolInLocalPath(symbol) {
    symbol = symbol.toUpperCase();
    return `../assets/assets-image/${symbol}.PNG`;
  }
```

Edit2: and in html i have this with onError attr:

```html
<img [src]="getAssetImageBySymbol(favorite.symbol)" onError="this.src='assets/images/asset-error.png'" />
```

Comment: could you share the code with us?

Comment: sorry, edited with the code now

Comment: i would use pipes instead of direct function calls in the template. But you could simply check in the getImageBySymbolInLocalPath(s) function if the image exists or not. If it doesn't exist you can return the path to the asset-error.png

Comment: i tried to do something like this ``return `../assets/assets-image/${symbol}.PNG` ? `../assets/assets-image/${symbol}.PNG` : 'assets/images/asset-error.png';`` but doenst work

Comment: yes this won't work because you are checking if a string is null. Ill post a working answer down below.

Comment: if my answer was helpful you could mark it as "correct" :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  getImageBySymbolInLocalPath(symbol) {
    try{
      symbol = symbol.toUpperCase();
      return `../assets/assets-image/${symbol}.PNG`;
    catch(err){
      return "Some static image url with not found name or we say default image url";
    }
  }
```

Try above code... Happy coding... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
getImageBySymbolInLocalPath(symbol) {
  let image = new Image();
  let url_image = 'your image url';
  image.src = url_image;
  if (image.width !== 0) {
     return `image url`;
  } else {
     return `error image url`;
  }
}
```

this will work. You try to create an image with the path you predefined and then you try to read its width. If the width is zero then the image doesn't exist and you can return the string for the error image.